# VB.NET DataGridView Not Showing Data

Tags: vb.net, arrays, datagridview, multidimensional-array

I have looked around quite a bit, and nothing seems to answer my question in particular. I have DataGridView in which I add rows and columns dependent on a certain record count of geospatial data that is held in ArcGIS. The data is then passed through to the gridview for editing.

So I do not use any databinding methods, rather it is a very manual process. I store data into a two-dimensional arrays, which indexes are based off of those certain data record counts.

After the loops are complete, the data should be stored in each cell dependent on index. The very last row that was populated is populated perfectly, yet the other 72 (or so) rows are blank.

Here is the code as follows:

**This populates column headers (works great):**

```
For i_FieldNum = 0 To pFields_1.FieldCount - 1

        str_FieldName = UCase(pFields_1.Field(i_FieldNum).Name)
        str_FieldAliasName = pFields_1.Field(i_FieldNum).AliasName

        ReDim Preserve m_array_str_FieldNames(i_FieldNum)
        ReDim Preserve m_array_str_FieldAliasNames(i_FieldNum)
        m_array_str_FieldNames(i_FieldNum) = str_FieldName
        m_array_str_FieldAliasNames(i_FieldNum) = str_FieldAliasName

        i_FieldCount = i_FieldCount + 1
        i_ColNum = i_FieldCount - 1

        'If this is the "SHAPE", "FID", or "OBJECTID" field, remember it:
        If (str_FieldName = "SHAPE") Then
            m_i_FieldNum_Shape = i_FieldCount - 1
        ElseIf (str_FieldName = "FID") Then
            m_i_FieldNum_FID = i_FieldCount - 1
        ElseIf (str_FieldName = "OBJECTID") Then
            m_i_FieldNum_OBJECTID = i_FieldCount - 1
        End If

        'Store the field name in the top row:
        grid_Data.ColumnCount = i_FieldCount
        grid_Data.Columns.Item(i_ColNum).HeaderText = str_FieldName

        ReDim Preserve m_array_l_FieldColLengths(i_ColNum)
        m_array_l_FieldColLengths(i_ColNum) = pFields_1.Field(i_FieldNum).Length

    Next i_FieldNum
```

**This populates the two-dimensional array:**

```
 Do Until pFeat_1 Is Nothing
        'Until we run out of features ...

        i_FeatCount = i_FeatCount + 1


        For i_FieldNum = 0 To pFields_1.FieldCount - 1

        'If the field is recorded as a shape
            If (i_FieldNum = m_i_FieldNum_Shape) Then
                array_Data(i_FeatCount - 1, i_FieldNum) = "<Shape>"
            Else

        'If the value of the field is null
                If IsNothing(pFeat_1.Value(i_FieldNum)) Or pFeat_1.Value(i_FieldNum).ToString = "" Then
                    array_Data(i_FeatCount - 1, i_FieldNum) = "<Null>"
                Else

                    array_Data(i_FeatCount - 1, i_FieldNum) = pFeat_1.Value(i_FieldNum).ToString
                End If
            End If

        Next i_FieldNum

        'End If

        'Move to the next feature (if any).
        pFeat_1 = pFeatCursor_1.NextFeature


    Loop
```

**This is suppose to display the data:**

```
 For i_RowNum = 0 To i_FeatCount - 1

        'Add a new row to the grid:
        grid_Data.RowCount = i_RowNum + 2

        For i_ColNum = 0 To pFields_1.FieldCount - 1

            grid_Data.Item(i_ColNum, i_RowNum + 1).Value = array_Data(i_RowNum, i_ColNum)

        Next i_ColNum

    Next i_RowNum
```

Everything runs and compiles perfectly, although as I stated before, only the last row's data is shown (which is populated properly).

If anyone can help figure out why only one row is populated, it would be more than appreciated.

Thank You,

Logan

Comment: Must confess I can't see it. As an aside though if you set grid_data.RowCount to i_FeatCount outside the loop, you'll get a performance improvement.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. This is driving me insane. I have sat through all iterations, checking every value. Took me 4 and a half hours. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm going to have a try, I see you've come from VB6 background, unless oyur still on version 1.1 of .Net I'd recommend you change from ReDim'ing arrays to using generics, eg: List(of Class). Even using a DataTable would be much easier to read. Tip hungarian notation isn't needed with .Net.

Comment: Are the row and column the correct way round here - grid_Data.Item(i_ColNum, i_RowNum + 1) ?

Comment: yes Phil they are. If anyone wants to put the first 4 lines of code in my answer in Visual Studio, drag in a DataGridView and run the code you can see the behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your updated section -**This is suppose to display the data:** If you data is correctly set then as per my guess it making grid to show wrong data. Modify it as per your columns in your grid that you have added. Or you can create column names string array to put data in particular cells. as `dgvr.Cells(columnsArray[index]).Value = array[,]`

```
For i_RowNum = 0 To i_FeatCount - 1

        'Add a new row to the grid:
        DataGridViewRow dgvr = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow();
        dgvr.CreateCells(grid_Data)

        For i_ColNum = 0 To pFields_1.FieldCount - 1
            dgvr.Cells(i_ColNum).Value = array_Data(i_RowNum, i_ColNum)
        Next i_ColNum
        grid_Data.Rows.Add(dgvr)
Next i_RowNum
```

> **Ref**: [Adding a New Row to DataGridView](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/3cf35ca3-67de-462a-8096-ad8c55e2259f/) and [How to: Manipulate
>   Rows in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddtce152.aspx)

Comment: You my friend, just fixed my problem. And it is quick;). Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

See here, each time you increment the row count its clearing out the data:

```
DataGridView1.RowCount += 1
DataGridView1.Item(0, 0).Value = "a value"
DataGridView1.RowCount += 1
DataGridView1.Item(0, 1).Value = "the previous value has been wiped"
```

To fix your code without any major changes, just use this method to add rows:

```
grid_Data.Rows.Add(paramArray)
```

or even easier put this line above the for loop and set the number of rows before you fill them in:

```
grid_Data.RowCount = i_FeatCount - 1
```